# Explicitly select items from a list or tuple

Tags: python, list, select, indexing, tuples

I have the following Python list (can also be a tuple):

```
myList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']
```

I can say

```
>>> myList[0:3]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> myList[::2]
['foo', 'baz']
>>> myList[1::2]
['bar', 'quux']
```

How do I explicitly pick out items whose indices have no specific patterns? For example, I want to select `[0,2,3]`. Or from a very big list of 1000 items, I want to select `[87, 342, 217, 998, 500]`. Is there some Python syntax that does that? Something that looks like:

```
>>> myBigList[87, 342, 217, 998, 500]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index) appears to be a duplicate. The other question has more up votes but this seems like it has a better answer with timings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

```
list( myBigList[i] for i in [87, 342, 217, 998, 500] )
```

---

I compared the answers with python 2.5.2:

- 19.7 usec: `[ myBigList[i] for i in [87, 342, 217, 998, 500] ]`
- 20.6 usec: `map(myBigList.__getitem__, (87, 342, 217, 998, 500))`
- 22.7 usec: `itemgetter(87, 342, 217, 998, 500)(myBigList)`
- 24.6 usec: `list( myBigList[i] for i in [87, 342, 217, 998, 500] )`

Note that in Python 3, the 1st was changed to be the same as the 4th.

---

Another option would be to start out with a `numpy.array` which allows indexing via a list or a `numpy.array`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> myBigList = numpy.array(range(1000))
>>> myBigList[(87, 342, 217, 998, 500)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index
>>> myBigList[[87, 342, 217, 998, 500]]
array([ 87, 342, 217, 998, 500])
>>> myBigList[numpy.array([87, 342, 217, 998, 500])]
array([ 87, 342, 217, 998, 500])
```

The `tuple` doesn't work the same way as those are slices.

Comment: Preferably as a list comp, `[myBigList[i] for i in [87, 342, 217, 998, 500]]`, but I like this approach the best.

Comment: @MedhatHelmy That's already in the answer. The third option used `from operator import itemgetter` in the initialization part of `python -mtimeit`.

Comment: I wonder, just from a language design perspective, why `myBigList[(87, 342, 217, 998, 500)]` doesn't work when `myBigList` is a regular python `list`?  When I try that I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.  That would be so much easier than typing out the comprehension - is there a language design/implementation issue involved?

Comment: @sparc_spread, this is because `lists` in Python only accept integers or slices. Passing an integer makes sure that only one item is retrieved from an existing list. Passing a slice makes sure a part of it is retrieved, but passing a tuple is like passing a data-type(`tuple`) as an argument to another data-type(`list`) which is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: why `list( myBigList[i] for i in [87, 342, 217, 998, 500] )` and not `[ myBigList[i] for i in [87, 342, 217, 998, 500] ]`

Comment: @Qbik Because in Python 2, it does not leak the loop variable as a new scope is created for the generator expression. One does not need to do it for Python 3 as the list comprehension has been changed to do that. I prefer it though as it makes it easier to swap out list for any other generator consuming function. This is also the reason that I don't care for either dictionary comprehensions nor set comprehensions.

Answer (score 60):

What about this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
itemgetter(0,2,3)(myList)
('foo', 'baz', 'quux')
```

Comment: This is the sexiest so far. Love that `operator` module!

Answer (score 18):

Maybe a list comprehension is in order:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print [ L[index] for index in [1,3,5] ]
```

Produces:

```
['b', 'd', 'f']
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 11):

It isn't built-in, but you can make a subclass of list that takes tuples as "indexes" if you'd like:

```
class MyList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, tuple):
            return [self[i] for i in index]
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(index)


seq = MyList("foo bar baaz quux mumble".split())
print seq[0]
print seq[2,4]
print seq[1::2]
```

printing

```
foo
['baaz', 'mumble']
['bar', 'quux']
```

Comment: (+1) Neat solution!  With this extension, handling arrays in Python starts to look much R or Matlab.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> map(myList.__getitem__, (2,2,1,3))
('baz', 'baz', 'bar', 'quux')
```

You can also create your own `List` class which supports tuples as arguments to `__getitem__` if you want to be able to do `myList[(2,2,1,3)]`.

Comment: While this works it's usually not a good idea to directly invoke magic variables. You're better off using a list comprehension or a helper module like `operator`.

Comment: @jathanism: I have to respectfully disagree. Though if you are concerned about forward compatibility (as opposed to public/private) I can definitely see where you're coming from.

Comment: That is where I'm coming from. :) Following that, it's the same reason why it's better to use `len(myList)` over `myList.__len__()`.

Comment: a creative solution.I don't think it's a bad idea to invoke magic variable.  programmer selects their preferred way based on programming circumstances.

Comment: Using magic methods is generally bad, so it's better to just avoid it. It's never necessary except maybe for performance reasons. IDK if there's anything specific about `__getitem__()`, but for other examples, see [Why does calling Python's 'magic method' not do type conversion like it would for the corresponding operator?](/q/54775946/4518341) and [Is there any case where len(someObj) does not call someObj's `__len__` function?](/q/496009/4518341).

Comment: Those magic method counterexamples are all about how the magic method implements a "building block" that may be used as part of a more complicated protocol. I see no reason not to use it, since we are not expecting the more complicated protocol (or in this case the method is the protocol basically). Happy to be proven wrong though. Using this will make your code possibly throw IndexError on invalid indices etc. (but than again your code may also work with negative indexes which can be a positive) -- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Answer (score 4):

I just want to point out, even syntax of itemgetter looks really neat, but it's kinda slow when perform on large list.

```
import timeit
from operator import itemgetter
start=timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(1000000):
    itemgetter(0,2,3)(myList)
print ("Itemgetter took ", (timeit.default_timer()-start))
```

Itemgetter took  1.065209062149279

```
start=timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(1000000):
    myList[0],myList[2],myList[3]
print ("Multiple slice took ", (timeit.default_timer()-start))
```

Multiple slice took  0.6225321444745759

Comment: First snippet, please add `myList = np.array(range(1000000))` otherwise you will get error.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
sek=[]
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
for i in [2, 4, 7, 0, 3]:
   a=[L[i]]
   sek=sek+a
print (sek)
```

Answer (score 1):

like often when you have a boolean numpy array like `mask`

`[mylist[i] for i in np.arange(len(mask), dtype=int)[mask]]`

A lambda that works for any sequence or np.array:

`subseq = lambda myseq, mask : [myseq[i] for i in np.arange(len(mask), dtype=int)[mask]]`

`newseq = subseq(myseq, mask)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line lambda:

```
list(map(lambda x: mylist[x],indices))
```

where:

```
mylist=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
indices = [3, 5, 0, 2, 6]
```

output:

```
['d', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'g']
```