# Remove element from tuple in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've knocking my head against a wall with this:

Basically what I want is to remove " " items from this list of tuples:

```
[('650', '724', '6354', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '650', '723', '4539')]
```

and obtain the following new list:

```
[('650', '724', '6354'), ('650', '723', '4539')]
```

any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6632188/544198

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Tuples in Python are *immutable*. This means that once you have created a tuple, you can't change the elements contained within it. However, you can create a *new* tuple that doesn't contain the items you don't want. For example:

```
>>> a = [('650', '724', '6354', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '650', '723', '4539')]
>>> [tuple(y for y in x if y) for x in a]
[('650', '724', '6354'), ('650', '723', '4539')]
```

This uses a list comprehension `[... for x in a]` to create a new list using the formula in `...`. That uses a generator expression `y for y in x if y` to create a new tuple containing the elements of `x` *only* if `y` is true (meaning the value is truthy, or the string is nonblank).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('650', '724', '6354', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '650', '723', '4539')]

print [tuple(x for x in y if x) for y in a]
```