# List indexing in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `a=[10,5,6,8]` and `b=[1,3]`.  How can I use the latter as a subscript of the former? I.e. I would like to extract the second and fourth element of `a`.

Put otherwise, [in Matlab I would use](http://www.mathworks.fr/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

```
v = [16 5 9 4 2 11 7 14];

v([1 5 6])      % Extract the first, fifth, and sixth elements
>>  ans =
        16   2   11
```

How can I do the same in Python?

Comment: If you're coming from Matlab, will you be using these lists for matlab-like array operations?

Comment: To add a note, array index starts from 0 in python.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index

Comment: @shahkalpesh I think they understand that, as the `[1,3]` corresponds with the explanation of *I would like to extract the second and fourth element*

Comment: @JonClements: My comment is based on the question where v[1, 5, 6] returns 16, 2, 11 in matlab. In python, it will return 5, 11, 7

Comment: @shahkalpesh good point... well made... I retract my comment somewhat :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to do it:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a=[10,5,6,8]
b=[1,3]
res = itemgetter(*b)(a)
# (5, 8)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
>>> a = [10, 5, 6, 8]
>>> b = [1, 3]
>>> [a[x] for x in b]
[5, 8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) supports indexing with arrays, as well as a bunch of other array and matrix operations, in Matlab style. Consider using it for computationally intensive tasks:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([10,5,6,8])

In [3]: b = np.array([1,3])

In [4]: a[b]
Out[4]: array([5, 8])
```

Comment: While the answer is helpful, numpy isnt part of standard module. So, it will be downloading something for the functionality OP asked.

Comment: @shahkalpesh it's fine to assume that if coming from matlab, the OP will either want or already have installed numpy/scipy/pandas etc...

Comment: @JonClements: I dont have that background to assume things. List comprehension is built in, so it is straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

```
l=[1 5 6]
v = [16 5 9 4 2 11 7 14];
[v[i] for i in l]
```

you can try like this

it can be explained like this

```
for i in l:
    print v[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[10,5,6,8]
b=[1,3]

ex = [a[i] for i in b]
print(ex) # [5, 8]
```