# Get same object in multi Querysets in Python Django

Tags: python, django

Hope you guys help me to Get same object in multi Querysets in Python. I use Django Framework

I assumed that I have 2 Queryset:

```
qrs1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9]
```

and

```
qrs2 = [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

I want to print result with this queryset:

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: That is help you :https://stackoverflow.com/q/18272160/5747242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your first queryset to set and call [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#frozenset.intersection) method of this set.

```
set(qrs1).intersection(qrs2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 qrs1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9]
 qrs2 = [1, 4, 2, 5]
 list(set(qrs1).intersection(qrs2))
```

you just need an intersection of the querysets