# Slice lists at different indices at the same time in python

Tags: python

How can I check if two lists have same values at specific index, using slice?

```
L1 = ['X00013', 9654123, 4.1, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 90.01]
L2 = ['X00014', 2021230, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001]
```

I know how to check

```
if L1[3] == L2[3]:
    print("YES")
```

but I do not know how to check for multiple locations/indices at the same time:

I'm looking for something like checking both lists at indices 3,4 and 7 at the same time.

I can use operator and `itemgetter`:

```
itemgetter(3,4,7)(L1) ==  itemgetter(3,4,7)(L2)
```

but I would like the simple direct solution slicing the lists. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Slices have to be start:stop:step, which 3,4,7 is not.  Personally, I would just write a plain old for loop and check the indices one by one for this.  Or, use numpy arrays, which have this feature.

Comment: `if all(L1[i] == L2[i] for i in (3, 4, 7):`?

Comment: Without slicing, you can get all indices where L1 matches L2 using `[i for i in range(len(L1)) if L1[i] == L2[i]]`

Comment: if OP's goal is to slice, I'd agree with @wim (same as in duplicate question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index)

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Won't this produce tuple index out of range?

Comment: @Arnaud yes figured it out too late to edit

Comment: @MathiasEttinger it was an error in the OP's code, he fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through a list of desired indices.

```
places = (3, 4, 7)

if [L1[i] for i in places] ==     \
   [L2[i] for i in places]:
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

Of course, this reduces to a simple `if all`, but the above might help you understand the logic.

```
print all(L1[i] == L2[i] for i in places)
```

Comment: Actually using the `all` is logically different.  It's possible for the first code to raise an `IndexError` whilst the second code returns a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just a basic loop and some conditions:

```
def check_places(L1, L2, places):
    for i in places:
        if i >= len(L1) or i >= len(L2) or L1[i] != L2[i]:
            return False

    return True
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> L1 = ['X00013', 9654123, 4.1, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 90.01]
>>> L2 = ['X00014', 2021230, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001]
>>> places = (3, 4, 7)
>>> check_places(L1, L2, places)
False
```