# Python array[array[ ] ]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

What does it mean when an array is used as another array's index? This is the code I saw, and I don't understand

```
res = center[label.flatten()]
```

center and label come from the opencv method kmeans.

```
ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(flat, K, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
center = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8([center]), cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
center = center[0]
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that both `center` and `label.flatten()` are arrays? Could you show us their initialization?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @pilu center and label come from the opencv method, kmeans. I've added the line where they are initialized to that it's clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get multiple elements by index using an `np.ndarray`. In your case
`label.flatten()` is an array of the indices of the the array `center` that you need. For example if `center` is an array of k-means centroids, then this operation selects some of those centers.

A minimal example:

```
a = np.array([-2, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5, 6])
b = [1, 2, 5]

print(list(a[b])) # Prints [1, 5, 5]
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index) question.

Answer (score 0):

I also worked with this algorithm of K means.

1) In centers you would have k points.
2) In labels you would have k clustered numbered array. `i.e for k = 3 label = [0,1,0,2,0,1 ... ]` something like this.

what `res = center[label.flatten()]` it does is, it paste center point in label array instead of just 0,1,2

For example if centers were [123,212,41] then this `res = center[label.flatten()]` will make label array look like `[123,212,123,41,123,212 ....]`