# Is there a common name for a function that maps by an index?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, idioms

Names such as `map`, `filter` or `sum` are generally understood by every resonably good programmer.

I wonder whether the following function `f` also has such a standard name:

```
def f(data, idx): return [data[i] for i in idx]
```

Example usages:

```
r = f(['world', '!', 'hello'], [2, 0, 1, 1, 1])

piecePrice = [100, 50, 20, 180]
pieceIdx = [0, 2, 3, 0, 0]
total Price = sum(f(piecePrice, pieceIdx))
```

I started with `map`, but `map` is generally understood as a function that applies a function on each element of a list.

Comment: If `idx` were a contiguous sequence of consecutive integers, I might call it a slice or substring or subsequence. If the number of indices in `idx` were equal to the number of elements in `data` (with no repeats in `idx`) I'd call it a permutation or a shuffle. Otherwise, most generally, I'd call it a multi-subset. I guess what I'm trying to say is that the specifics about what `idx` might bear on what it's called in a particular context.

Comment: I'd call that `select`

Comment: In NumPy it's called [`take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

Comment: There is also [`itemgetter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18272249/7851470) but it works differently.