# List Comprehensions if else repeating element every three items

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

There are too many questions of list comprehensions on this website, but none seem to match what I'd like to do. I have already done it with a for loop, but I was wondering if it could be done with list comprehensions, or if someone could direct me where I could find a similar case.

I have a list of functions:

```
function_list=[iron,cobalt,nickel,copper,zinc,vanadium,chromium,managenese,titanium,footer]
```

Each function is a question I ask to my students, exported to a PDF file. The last function on the list, is *footer* which makes the PDF file insert a page skip to the next page.

So usually, What does a simple quiz look like (so far)?

```
call_functions([x for x in function_list[0:3]] + [function_list[-1]])
```

generating

```
call_functions([iron,cobalt,nickel,footer]) #as desired
```

where *call_functions* is basically a PDF exporter. So my list comprehension adds three questions and skips to the next page, adding three more. As the number of questions grow, the code ends up looking like a mess:

```
call_functions([x for x in function_list[0:3]] + [function_list[-1]] + [x for x in function_list[3:6]]+ [function_list[-1]] + [x for x in function_list[6:9]])
```

generating

```
call_functions([iron,cobalt,nickel,footer,copper,zinc,vanadium,footer,chromium,managenese,titanium]) #as desired
```

although this works, I'm trying to make a single comprehension list that will iterate through the list and after every third element, it'll insert the last element on the list. Or even keep *footer* outside the list is also viable. But I can't get it to work.

I've tried:

```
[x for i,x in enumerate(function_list[0:9]) if i%3==0 function_list[-1] else x]
```

to SyntaxError.

Also tried:

```
[x if i%3==0 function_list[-1] else x for i,x in enumerate(function_list[0:9])]
```

Also to SyntaxError

Could someone tell me (or direct me to) what am I doing wrong, and/or direct to a similar case, please?

Thanks

Comment: is this the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index

Comment: general point `[x for x in function_list[0:3]` is just `function_list[:3]`

Comment: Regular for-loop will be more readable and less error prone. So maybe striving for list comprehension is what you actually doing wrong?

Comment: @Poolka The more I dig into list comprehensions on my particular case, the more I think you're right. But well, it was worth the try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
[func for i in range(0, len(function_list) - 1, 3) for func in function_list[i:i+3] + [function_list[-1]]]
```

output:

```
>>>

['iron',
 'cobalt',
 'nickel',
 'footer',
 'copper',
 'zinc',
 'vanadium',
 'footer',
 'chromium',
 'managenese',
 'titanium',
 'footer']
```

Comment: This seems to have an unwanted flatten.

Comment: @DanD. , OP listed: `[iron,cobalt,nickel,footer,copper,zinc,vanadium,footer,chromium,managenese,titanium] #as desired` which is flattened so I flattened it. My originial answer actually didn't include the flatten if you think that's what was desired:
`[function_list[i:i+3] + [function_list[-1]] for i in range(0, len(function_list) - 1, 3)]`

Comment: This is indeed a nice alternative! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I got it to work.

What worked for me was the following:

```
call_functions([x if (i+1)%4!=0 else function_list[-1] for i,x in enumerate(function_list)])
```

If I do

```
if i%4!=0 #making the fourth element function footer
```

I get a list that starts with the *footer* function. But doing:

```
if (i+1)%4!=0
```

I avoid the initial issue. I get:

```
call_functions([iron,cobalt,nickel,footer,copper,zinc,vanadium,footer,chromium,managenese,titanium,footer])
```

I'm sure there must be other ways to do this simpler and neater, any suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Ex.