# Creating boxplots with proper x axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm trying to make a boxplot of auto data of mpg per the number of cylinders. This is the code I have

```
cyls = list(set(np.array(auto.cylinders)))
data = []
for val in cyls:
    d = np.array(auto.loc[auto['cylinders'] == val].mpg)
    data.append(d)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(data, positions = cyls);
```

This was done in a jupyter notebook. It works fine, but it feels like kind of a roundabout solution, especially since this is apparently a lot easier in R. Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Comment: how do you define "proper"? it's an incredibly vague word

Comment: you should also provide your data. this code really doesn't make much sense without it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the most roundabout part of your solution is the for-loop.  I understand the pain, since MATLAB also has concise ways of accessing array elements.

It looks like you can make your solution a little more concise by replacing your for-loop with something like this:

```
data = [ auto[i].mpg for i in indices]
```

where `indices` is the array of desired indices for each automobile.

(See [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index))

But depending on how you have set up the `auto` object, it's possible that you could simply use

```
data = list(set(np.array(auto.mpg)))
```

to get the corresponding `mpg` values.