# How to apply image transform to a list of images and maintain the right dimensions?

Tags: pytorch

I'm using the Omniglot dataset, which is a set of 19,280 images, each which is 105 x 105 (grayscale).

I defined a custom Dataset class with the following transform:

```
class OmniglotDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, X, transform=None):
        self.X = X
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return self.X.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
        img = self.X[idx]
        if self.transform:
            img = self.transform(img)
        return img

img_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

X_train.shape
(19280, 105, 105)
train_dataset = OmniglotDataset(X_train, transform=img_transform)
```

When I index a single image, it returns the right dimensions:

```
train_dataset[0].shape
torch.Size([1, 105, 105])
```

But when I index several images, it returns the dimensions in the wrong order (I expect `3 x 105 x 105`):

```
train_dataset[[1,2,3]].shape
torch.Size([105, 3, 105])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error because try apply [transformation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#transforms-on-pil-image) of single image to list:

A more convenient way to get a batch of any size is to use Dataloader:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

img_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

omniglot = datasets.Omniglot(root='./data', background=True, download=True, transform = img_transform)

data_loader = DataLoader(omniglot, shuffle=False, batch_size = 8)
for image_batch in data_loader:
  # now image_batch contain first eight samples
  print(image_batch.shape) # torch.Size([8, 1, 105, 105]) 
  break
```

If you really need to get images in arbitrary order:

```
from operator import itemgetter

indexes = [1,3,5]
selected_samples = itemgetter(*b)(omniglot)
```

Comment: The problem is I want to index a specific list of images. Can I do it with a dataloader? I was under the impression it batches images randomly

Comment: With shuffle = False dataloader will not mix images: (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=dataloader#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)

But if you really need to get images in arbitrary order, you can do it, querying dataset as a list:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index

P.S. Add examples  to answer