# How to create a scalar index out of a int64 in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
valueXs = [7, 9, 10, 11, 8, 5, 2, 9, 18, 17, 15, 7]
diff = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(valueXs)))
maxi = np.where(diff < 0)[0]+1
```

but when I try: `valueXs[maxi]` I get the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Try to do `print(maxi)` and you will see the problem. It will also help you to read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You seem to be ignoring or unaware of the difference between arrays and lists. You can't index a list with an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index)

Answer (score 0):

```
valueXs = np.array([7, 9, 10, 11, 8, 5, 2, 9, 18, 17, 15, 7])
diff = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(valueXs)))
maxi = np.where(diff < 0)[0]+1
valueXs[maxi]
```

converted your valueXs to np.array to allow array indexing

Comment: Thanks, I still get confused with the types.