# Accessing values of list by different indices

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Hy,
I am fairly new to python. I am stuck with problem which is below explained,
We have two lists say

```
A = [0,3,4,6,7]   #indices
B = [1.2,5,1.3,0.5,7,0.6,0.43,5,3,6,4,1,5,7,4]   #values
```

where list A elements are actually indices of list B which I want to access and store in new list say C.
so my list C should be

```
C = [1.2,0.5,7,0.43 ,5]
```

And what if I have array instead of list?
Thank you for your time.....

Comment: Use a list comprehension that loops over `A` and returns `B[element]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index)

Comment: Use list comprehension: `C = [B[i] for i in A]`

Comment: Also, use lower case variable names for most purposes.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much :)

Comment: @Timur  thank you ,I hope  will learn this kind of  comprehension soon :)