# How to select multiple sets of elements from a list

Tags: python, list, indices

I want to select multiple groups of three or more elements from a list, according to some indices.

I thought of using `itemgetter`, but it does not work for multiple sets, for example

```
labels=['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6','C7','C8','C10','C13','C14','C15']
indexlist = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 10), 3))
ixs= [4,5]
a=[indexlist[ix] for ix in ixs]
from operator import itemgetter
print(*itemgetter(*a[0])(labels))
```

where

```
a=[(1, 2, 7), (1, 2, 8)]
```

works well, whereas

```
labels=['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6','C7','C8','C10','C13','C14','C15']
indexlist = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 10), 3))
ixs= [4,5]
a=[indexlist[ix] for ix in ixs]
from operator import itemgetter
print(*itemgetter(*a)(labels))
```

gives the error

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Is there a way to pass multiple sets of indices to `itemgetter`, or is there some other convenient alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse several indexes, as stated. To make it easier you can use numpy.

```
labels = np.array(['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6','C7','C8','C10','C13','C14','C15'])
print([list(labels[index_tuples])] for index_tuples in a)
```

What this is doing is getting multiple sets of indexes using your tuples and printing them as a list.

Source: [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index)

Comment: I am not sure how to use that generator, if I inquire ```list(labels[a[0]])``` I get ```IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 3 were indexed```