# How to figure out list elements associated with a list of indexes

Tags: python

I have a couple of lists such as the following ones

```
A = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
B = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]
```

in list A all and only the positions 2, 3, 4, and 5 contain the number 2. What I am looking for are the B values associated with these indexes, which is

```
C = [2, 4, 3, 1]
```

Could you help me with this issue, please?

The way I figured out uses the following function

```
#https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-find-all-indexes-of-an-item-in-a-list/
def get_index_positions(list_of_elems, element):
    ''' Returns the indexes of all occurrences of give element in
    the list- listOfElements '''
    index_pos_list = []
    index_pos = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # Search for item in list from indexPos to the end of list
            index_pos = list_of_elems.index(element, index_pos)
            # Add the index position in list
            index_pos_list.append(index_pos)
            index_pos += 1
        except ValueError as e:
            break
    return index_pos_list
```

which provides me all the indexes of A list containing the value 2, as follows

```
idxs = get_index_positions(A, 2)
```

than I get

```
idxs = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Which makes me feel I am nearly there. However, I believe I need something smart and efficient to tell python to take all and only the B values associated with the idxs indexes

Anyone can suggest me anything?

Comment: You only have got the indices. To get the values from the indices `[B[idx] for idx in idxs]`

Comment: You can use numpy also as `import numpy as np np.array(B)[np.where(np.array(A)==2)].tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line using `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
A = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
B = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]

[b for a, b in zip(A, B) if a == 2]
```

Which gives the list: `[2, 4, 3, 1]`

The `zip` part lets you go through list `A` and list `B` simultaneously. The list comprehension is simply a more elegant way of writing:

```
new_list = []
for a, b in zip(A, B): 
    if a == 2:
        new_list.append(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Going from end to start, using other Stack Overflow questions to improve your code:

1. With your list of indexes, you can "fetch" the items from `B` according to - [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18272160/6045800):

   ```py
   C = [B[i] for i in idxs]
   ```
2. Going with the indexes approach, your function could be much simplified using - [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6294179/6045800):

   ```py
   def get_index_positions(list_of_elems, element):
       return [i for i, x in enumerate(list_of_elems) if x == element]
   ```
3. But really there is no need to bother with indexes at all. You can [iterate through two lists in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1663807/6045800) and take the desired elements:

   ```py
   C = [b for a, b in zip(A, B) if a == 2]
   ```