# How to split string and only assign needed fields

Tags: python

I want to split a string like this. I can do the following.

```
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 = 'field1_field2_field3_field4_field5'.split('_')
```

However, I only need let's say f1 and f4. I do not want to assign other fields (I do not want to keep the others in the memory). I guess I am looking for something like Perl's array slice notation.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index

Answer (score 3):

You could assign to `_` to indicate an unused value. (Note that this is only a convention and `_` is just a regular variable here.)

```py
f1, *_, f4, _ = 'field1_field2_field3_field4_field5'.split('_')
```

Comment: You should note that `_` is still a name, and the values are assigned to it as if it were any other name.

Comment: Could `del _` afterwards, although that’s not the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).

```
f1, f4 = 'field1_field2_field3_field4_field5'.split('_')[0:4:3]
```

This has the benefit of not assigning to other names. For this particular case, `[0:n:3]` where `n>3` or `n=-1` will work.

In general, to extract two elements from a sequence that are at indices `a` and `b` where `b>a`, using `[a:b+1:b-a]` is typically the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat intermediate variable names for fields you won't assign

```
f1, f4, f4, f4 = 'field1_field2_field3_field4_field5'.split('_')[:4]
```

But the saving in trivial memory allocation is probably not worth the loss in code clarity.

Alternatively, you could add one last `None` value to the unpacking list so the the `_` always ends up with a None value unallocating any intermediate values :

```
(f1, _, _, f4, *_), _ = 'field1_field2_field3_field4_field5'.split('_'),None
```