# Get last item in JSON array with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to grab the last item in a json array and haven't been able to come across any documentation that shows how to do this.

```json
{'numbers': [1, 2, 3]}
```

how do I just get 3?

ANSWERED:

```py
import json

array = json.load(str({'numbers': [1, 2, 3]}))
lastItem = array['numbers'][-1] # This is the format.
```

Comment: `['numbers'][-1]`?

Comment: What is in `page`?

Comment: semi-related in that it shows examples of numpy multi-dimensional array vs python list access https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index

Comment: yes @jonrsharpe thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of working with JSON in python is converting the JSON object to a dictionary and working from there.

If the JSON is a string:

```
f='{"numbers":["1", "2", "3"]}'
d=json.loads(f)
d['numbers'][-1]
```

If the JSON is in a file:

```
with open("test.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
d['numbers'][-1]
```