# Pandas indexer methods and tuples as parameters

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas `Series`, and I want to access a set of elements at specific indices, like so:

```
In [1]:
from pandas import Series
import numpy as np

s = Series(np.arange(0,10))

In [2]: s.loc[[3,7]]

Out[2]:
3    3
7    7
dtype: int64
```

The `.loc` method accepts a `list` as the parameter for this type of selection.  The `.iloc` and `.ix` methods work the same way.

However, if I use a `tuple` for the parameter, both `.loc` and `.iloc` fail:

```
In [5]: s.loc[(3,7)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
........
IndexingError: Too many indexers

In [6]: s.iloc[(3,7)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
........

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

And `.ix` produces a strange result:

```
In [7]: s.ix[(3,7)]
Out[7]: 3
```

Now, I get that you can't even do this with a raw python `list`:

```
In [27]:
x = list(range(0,10))
x[(3,7)]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-cefdde088328> in <module>()
      1 x = list(range(0,10))
----> 2 x[(3,7)]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

To retrieve a set of specific indices from a `list`, you need to use a comprehension, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632188/explicitly-select-items-from-a-python-list-or-tuple).

But on the other hand, using a `tuple` to select rows from a pandas `DataFrame` seems to work fine for all three indexing methods.  Here's an example with the `.loc` method:

```
In [8]:
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({"x" : np.arange(0,10)})

In [9]:
df.loc[(3,7),"x"]

Out[9]:
3    3
7    7
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

My three questions are:

- Why won't the `Series` indexers accept a `tuple`?  It would seem
  natural to use a `tuple` since the set of desired indices is an
  immutable, single-use parameter. Is this solely for the purpose of
  mimicking the `list` interface?
- What is the explanation for the strange `Series` `.ix` result?
- Why the inconsistency between `Series` and `DataFrame` on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to first question is that `tuples` are used to locate in a `MultiIndex`. I don't think there are good answers to the second two questions except that you've exposed a bug and an inconsistency, respectively, in the code (This isn't that hard to do :)). 
So the `Series` complains because you don't have a 
`MultiIndex` or, more generally, that the length of the tuple is greater than the number of levels in your index. 
The `DataFrame` should probably react in the same way but doesn't. 
I think the safest way to proceed is to reserve `tuples` for `MultiIndex` and to use lists/arrays/series for indexing multiple rows. 
As a side note, you would use a list/array of tuples to select multiple rows in a `MultiIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer this in a systematic way, so I'll just answer list-style:

1. I think the bigger question may be what exactly are you trying to do but are not able to?  I.e. why do you want to use `()` instead of `[]` when `[]` is the standard way?
2. Your first question is really just about why the syntax is a certain way and that's almost an impossible question to answer without going deep into the history of not just pandas but also numpy.  In any event, @JoeCondron's simple answer is correct:  tuples are for multi-indexes and lists are for advanced indexing (aka "fancy indexing").  I believe that fancy indexing was lifted directly from numpy and multi-indexes were added by pandas.
3. For your last question, I guess this is an inconsistency, but Series and DataFrames are not the exact same thing, so it's not really possible for their behavior to be 100% consistent.  In particular, DataFrame indexing requires extra machinery to distinguish between rows and columns whereas a Series only has to worry about rows.
4. To answer your question in a very general sense, I think what you show here is that when you use non-standard syntax it *might* nevertheless work as you want, but it might not.  So I don't think it's fair to say that `df.loc` worked here and `s.loc` didn't.  Neither was guaranteed to work here (according to the documentation), but `df.loc` happened to.  Furthermore, it is quite possible `df.loc` would stop working like this in a future version.
5. If you do find an example of `loc/iloc/ix` **not working as shown in the documentation**, that should be pointed out and reported as a bug.  I don't believe any of the above fall into that category but I could certainly be wrong about that.

Comment: Agreed on all.  To answer your first question, all I'm trying to do is use a syntax that I would think would be natural.  You would think that a specific set of index numbers would be as immutable as things get, and a `tuple` would make sense. It's not the end of the world that I can't use a `tuple`, nor am I particularly hung up on that. In the end, not being able to do it didn't frustrate me so much as trigger my curiosity.

Comment: Great answer. I would argue though that `s.ix[(3, 7)]` returning `3` is a bug. I can't imagine how this could be the intended behaviour and I think it's an example of how unexpected inputs are sometime not handled well in Pandas.

Comment: @JoeCondron  yes, good point!  totally agree with you on that.