# Python dictionary select multiple keys by index

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary where I'd like to select multiple keys by index that are out of order. Something like this works for keys in order -

```
list(result)[0:2]
```

But I would like only index 0 and 2 -

```
list(result)[0,2]
```

I've tried a number of varieties of this, but what am I missing? Thank you

Comment: dictionaries don't have indicies. They are *maps* from keys to values. If you need to do this, you should consider an alternative data structure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explicitly select items from a list or tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632188/explicitly-select-items-from-a-list-or-tuple) or [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18272160/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
result = list(result)
new_result = [result[i] for i in list_of_indices]
```