# replace the values of an np array with its correspondent name

Tags: python

I have list with names and their correspondent number. Is there any easy way to replace the correspondent number in a n array back with the correct name? here is an example thanks!

```
list =[{'Nikolas', 'Kate', 'George'}, [0, 1, 2 ]]

np_array_1 = np.array([1, 2])
np_array_2= np.array([0])
etc.
```

I mean in a for loop or something, as I have plenty of arrays.

So I would like to get:

```
np_array_1 = ['Kate', 'George']
np_array_2= ['Nikolas']
```

Comment: Why are the names in a set? A set has no order so it is not guaranteed to match the numbers...

Comment: Also there are no numpy arrays here...

Comment: So how they should be so the order is guaranteed? thanks for the response

Comment: please do not override `list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explicitly select items from a list or tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632188/explicitly-select-items-from-a-list-or-tuple)

Comment: why is the first element of your list a set and the second element a list if they are supposed to have a 1 to 1 correspondence?

Comment: If you're using lists then just index in a loop: `np_array_1 = [l[0][i] for i in np_array_1]` and if it's actually an np array then just index with array: `np_array_1 = l[0][np_array_1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of set(set will not maintain order) make a nested list like:

```
lst =[['Nikolas', 'Kate', 'George'], [0, 1, 2 ]]
```

make a dictionary to store name and numbers:

```
d=dict(zip(lst[1],lst[0]))  # here 0 index in lst will have all the numbers and 1 index in lst will have all the names

print(d)
#{0: 'Nikolas', 1: 'Kate', 2: 'George'}
```

Now, if you want o replace numbers with names you can do:

suppose there is a list with numbers and y want to replace them with names

```
l=[1,0,2]
e=[]
for x in l: 
    e.append(d[x])

print(e)
#['Kate', 'Nikolas', 'George']
```

Comment: Now it is also easy (and readable) to transform to a simple list-comp: `e = [d[x] for x in l]`

Comment: Lastly, I guess you answered for the general case, but here it is obviously redundant to have a list which is the natural indexes... It can also just be `e = [lst[0][i] for i in l]` - no need for a dict (just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6632209/6045800)...)